# scale_x_date makes plot begins at April, not January in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

I am currently creating a time trend plot in `ggplot2`. I used `scale_x_date()` function to create `date_breaks` of 6 months and have them label at every 6 months, but the graph x-axis begins in April, not January.

```
library(lubridate)
library(stats)
library(ggplot2)

dates <- seq.Date(mdy("01-01-2013"), mdy("01-01-2017"), by = "month")
value <- rnorm(length(dates))
data <- cbind.data.frame(dates, value)

plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = dates, y = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "6 months",
               date_labels = "%b\n%Y")
```

The output x-axis begins in April.

[image]

I have also tried adding `expand = c(0,0)`:

```
plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = dates, y = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "6 months",
               date_labels = "%b\n%Y",
               expand = c(0,0))
```

but it results in:
[image: The Jan is right on the x-axis.]

Please advise!

Comment: please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: when someone ask for reproducible example it means for a sample data and the code you are using so the error can be reproduce, this way its impossible to get the same problem you are facing

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to ask a better question please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MLavoie here is an example.

Comment: @AlejandroAndrade here is an example!

Comment: @RuiBarradas I apologize. This was my first ever post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code, there is a mistake between dates and cdates. What about this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = cdates, y = value)) +
   geom_point() +
 scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"), as.Date("2017-01-01"), by="6 months"), date_labels = "%b\n%Y")
```

Comment: I apologize. That 'c' in 'cdates' must have been a typo from the post. The results are fixed!